# Does PHP 5.3.1 add a slash ("\") by default?

Tags: php

When I write

*input data*: `hel'l"lo`

`print_r($_POST)` *display* `hel\'\"lo`

and when I use

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){ 
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST);
```

*display*

```
hel\\\'\\\"lo
```

Because PHP automatically adds slashes, is it necessary to use  `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: Dear Sir, how do i accept when i didn't get  true and valuable answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, from version 5.3 onwards, there will be no slashes added by default. Also note that `addslashes` is **not** a replacement for `mysql_real_escape_string`; you can read more about that [here](http://securityreliks.securegossip.com/2011/02/sql-injection-bypassing-addslashes/).

Comment: so i have to use `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST);`

Comment: You should also being using the MySQLi extension instead of MySQL as it is deprecated as of PHP v5.5

Answer (score 2):

magic_quotes_gpc is deprecated option at php 5.3

Comment: so what should i do??
shoud i use `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST);`
or not?

Answer (score 0):

> is it necessary to use mysql_real_escape_string?

Yes. But **not** as a blanket encoding over `$_POST` or `$_GET`. That's applying an output-stage escaping mechanism to the input stage, which is the wrong thing and will mangle your strings in unexpected and unwanted ways.

You should keep your strings in raw form up until the moment you insert the string into another context. At *that* point only, you use the appropriate escaping function. With MySQL:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM items WHERE title='"+mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])+"'";
```

or with HTML:

```
<p>Title: <?php echo(htmlspecialchars($_POST['title'])) ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently used an hosting with PHP 5.3.6 with the option "magic_quotes_gpc" enabled.
Unfortunately it's a shared hosting so I could not change the config (Also "php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off" to .htaccess failed).

A code-level solution that worked for me was placing this at the beginning

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc() === 1)
{
    $_GET = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($_GET, JSON_HEX_APOS)), true);
    $_POST = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($_POST, JSON_HEX_APOS)), true);
    $_COOKIE = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($_COOKIE, JSON_HEX_APOS)), true);
    $_REQUEST = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($_REQUEST, JSON_HEX_APOS)), true);
}
```

See here too

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Answer (score 0):

magic solution found in internet honestly

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
```